# Learning Qt - Creating a QApplication

Tags: c++, qt

I'm re-learning c++ (I have 10 years Java experience) and I'm also learning Qt in the process...

I'm used to creating objects (in Java) via:

```
MyObject o = new MyObject();
```

But when creating a QApplication in c++, the examples simply show:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
app.setOrganizationName("My Company");
app.setApplicationName("The App");
```

So suddenly, I have a reference to "app" and no obvious (to me) assignment to app...

Is this pattern a c++ thing or specific to Qt?  What is this pattern called?

Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend not learning a UI and the C++ language at the same time.  I'd especially recommend not trying to learn the C++ language while using/learning Qt.  Qt extends the language and many of the things you can do while using Qt are not exactly easy/possible with C++ or even desired.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not really a Qt question but,

```
//You have an assignment to app  
QApplication app(argc, argv);
// is just the same as
QApplication *app = new QApplication(argc, argv);
```

In C++ you have the choice of creating objects locally (on the stack) or with new (on the heap).  Allocating it locally here makes more sense when the app object has a definite lifetime (the length of main) won't be deleted and recreated and only one exists.

One annoying feature of C++ (because of it's c heritage) is that accessing parts of the resulting object is different. If created directly you use "."  `app.name()`    but if allocated with new you need to use 'c' pointer notation  `app->name()`

ps. There are a few [Qt specific memory features](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/objecttrees.html). Qt does a lot of memory management for you, eg. copy-on-write, automatic delete. In Qt you rarely have to call delete for an object - for a C++ expert these are sometimes annoying but from Java it should look more natural.

Comment: The "is just the same as" part is misleading, especially to someone with Java experience. Not only the lifetime is different, as you mention later, but in second case there is also the need to delete the pointer - Qt won't do it automatically in this case, obviously.

Answer (score 5):

The variable `app` is created on the stack on the line `QApplication app(argc, argv);` it calls `QApplication`'s constructor with arguments `argc` and `argv` which creates `QApplication` object called `app` in this case.

It's not a feature specific to Qt. You can allocate any non-virtual class with constructor this way as well. Also, it works on primitives so you can do for example this:

```
int val(1); // Equivalent to: int val = 1;
```

which would create integer variable named `val` with value 1.

You could allocate the QApplication object on heap using `new` and use it like this:

```
QApplication* app = new QApplication(argc, argv); // Heap allocation
app->setOrganizationName("My Company"); // Notice the -> instead of .
app->setApplicationName("The App");
```

The `->` is basically a shortcut for dereferencing the pointer and using `.`

Allocating on the stack is usually preferable (but not always feasible), because then you do not have to care about the object's lifetime (with either some smart pointer or raw `delete`), stack allocating is also usually less expensive than allocating on the heap.